# How to use .format with a variable rather than text in python

Tags: python, format, substitution

I'm trying to replace a couple of placeholders in a string variable using .format(arg1,arg2) in the same way that I could with defining literal text to .format although I'm clearly taking the wrong approach as .format does not see the placeholders.

In a literal way I might do

```
var = """ this is a
{0} {1} """.format(colour, animal)
```

which would work just fine.

I have now moved that templated text into a text file, that I have read in, but want to substitute the args at run time.

What is the best way to achieve that please?

Comment: `template.format(colour, animal)` - works just as well with variables as with hard-coded string constants (`format` is a method of a string object)

Comment: And if the above does not work, then you'll need to provide an example of the contents of your text file and how you are reading it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`format` is a method of a string object and will work just as well with a string held in a variable as with a hard-coded string constant.

So you can have for example:

`template.txt`

```
this is a
{0} {1}
```

and use this to read it and substitute the values:

```
with open("template.txt") as f:
    template = f.read().strip()

colour = "red"
animal = "lion"

print(template.format(colour, animal))
```

Gives:

```
this is a
red lion
```

You can also use keywords to substitute, which would give you more flexibility about the ordering of the colour and the animal (or indeed, for the same token to appear multiple times or not at all).

Here is a template:
`template.txt`

```
This is a {colour} {animal}
```

Substitute using keywords:

```
with open("template.txt") as f:
    template = f.read().strip()

colour = "red"
animal = "lion"

print(template.format(colour=colour, animal=animal))
```

gives:

```
This is a red lion
```

But now, as an example, here is an template which would be suitable for the Welsh language, where the order would be swapped round:

`template.txt`

```
{animal} {colour} ydy hon
```

Now substitute similarly:

```
print(template.format(colour="goch", animal="draig"))
```

```
draig goch ydy hon
```

It didn't matter that your format call had the items in the other order in the code, because they were matched up with the relevant keywords.

Again, this is no different from what you can do with hard-coded string constants.

Answer (score 0):

```
var = """this is a {0} {1} """

print(var.format("red", "dog"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    var = f.read().format(colour, animal)
```